# Java exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.Timer cannot be cast to javax.swing.JButton

Tags: java, swing, classcastexception

I dont really understand this run time error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.Timer cannot be cast to
>   javax.swing.JButton.

Here is my code:

```
timer = new Timer(DELAY, new ButtonListener());

private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[3];
buttons[0] = new JButton("Circle");
buttons[1] = new JButton("Start");
buttons[2] = new JButton("Stop");

for(JButton button : buttons){
  button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
  controlPanel.add(button);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
 JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

 if(button.getText().equals("Start")){
    timer.start();
 }else 
  if(button.getText().equals("Stop")){
    timer.stop();
 }else
  if(button.getText().equals("Circle")){
    shapes[count] = new Circle();
    drawPanel.repaint();
    count++;
 }
}
```

Comment: Put all the related code. What is e?

Comment: Seems `Exception` here: `JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();`. Show how you create `timer`

Comment: when your actionPerformed method get call?

Comment: Here is the code that creates the timer: timer = new Timer(10, new ButtonListener());

Comment: Why are you adding both the same listener to the timer _and_ the button. Create different ones for each. A timer is not a button. And vice versa. The source when you add it the Timer is the Timer, not the button

Comment: what is your ButtonListner class?

Comment: Besides, the listener code you have won't even do anything if you add it to the timer. What exactly do you expect to happen every `DELAY` milliseconds? Just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing Timers can also fire action events. You just need to do a class check in the code :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


    if (e.getSource() instanceof (JButton)) {

        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

        if(button.getText().equals("Start")){
            timer.start();
        }else
        if(button.getText().equals("Stop")){
            timer.stop();
        }else
        if(button.getText().equals("Circle")){
            shapes[count] = new Circle();
            drawPanel.repaint();
            count++;
        }


    }else (e.getSource() instanceof (Timer)) {
        //deal with timer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem in next line `JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();` in `actionPerformed()` method. Because you add `ButtonListener` to `JButton` and to `Timer`. You can use different listeners for them, or you can validate type of `e.getSource();` in  `actionPerformed()`

Answer (score 0):

In your actionPerformed method check if `e.getSource()` is an instance of `JButton` other wise don't process is

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
          // your button action logic
     }
}
```

Don't use same listener class for both `JButtons` and `JTimer`. Create a seperate Listener for your timer.